# Send Ajax when click on Publish in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I type this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#publish').click(function() {
        var postID=$('#post_ID').attr('value');
        alert(postID);
        $.ajax({
                url:"/wp-admin/spracovanie.php",
                method: "GET",
                data: {clanok: <?php echo $post_id;?>},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This script is saved in file post.php in wp-admin. When i click on #publish, **script alerts right ID**, but **ajax request failed**.
In Firebug i see "GET http://www.sktipy.sk/wp-admin/spracovanie.php?clanok=2854" type with red font, param is ok, file exists - right now just echo something. Where is problem? In file spracovanie.php i want make some insert in my database.

Comment: there is unused variable postID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to `preventDefault()` as the publish button might be doing something else, such as posting it's own content with it's defualt intended behaviour before your JS gets a chance to run the ajax. 
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

EDIT: Added the `one` method to only attach the click listener once and then trigger the click on the success of the ajax method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#publish').one('click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var postID=$('#post_ID').attr('value');
        alert(postID);
        $.ajax({
                url:"/wp-admin/spracovanie.php",
                method: "GET",
                data: {clanok: <?php echo $post_id;?>},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    // Now trigger click on button again
                    $('#publish').trigger( "click" );
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it calls my script a send request right, but basic wordpress scripts stop working. Whats now with new problem?

Comment: You can then trigger the click of the wordpress button in the success function of the ajax call.  Will update answer to attach you listener only `once` http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: .one("click", ...) worked for me, thank you x1000 !!